# Load Zend Framework and its application in a PHP script

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to lo the **Zend Framework** and its **MVC application** in a **PHP script** so I could do some models to query the database. The framework and some libs are loaded this way (the script was created by someone else):

```
    /** Initialise Zend  */
define( 'BRIDGE_BASE_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
set_include_path( get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.BRIDGE_BASE_DIR.'/../library' );

require_once('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
require_once 'Zend/Config/Ini.php';

$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->registerNamespace('XYz');
$autoloader->registerNamespace('Yxz');
```

I would like to call a model this way: `Franchisee_Model_Franchisee::find($franchiseeId)`

which is located under: `application/modules/franchisee/models/franchisee`

I tried many ways but I cannot load the full stack. Is there a simple way to load ZF in a script, including everything under application and application/modules?

UPDATE

I tried this too:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE );

/** Initialise Zend  */
define( 'BRIDGE_BASE_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
set_include_path( get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.BRIDGE_BASE_DIR.'/../library' );

require_once('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
require_once 'Zend/Config/Ini.php';

$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->registerNamespace('Xyz');
$autoloader->registerNamespace('Yzx');


/** Handle arguments */
if ($argc < 2) {
  echo 'LOG: ' . Zend_Date::now()->toString('YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss') . ' Please set the environment.'.PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}

define("APPLICATION_ENV", $argv[1]);
// echo 'LOG: ' . Zend_Date::now()->toString('YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss');
// echo " Current environment is: ".APPLICATION_ENV.PHP_EOL;

/** Zend_Application */
define(APPLICATION_PATH, dirname( __FILE__ ).'/../application');
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap();

echo "Running ZF version: " . Zend_Version::VERSION;

new Admin_Contract_Table();
```

but I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Contract_Table' not found in /Users/myuser/dev/htdocs/Admin/current/vend_bridge/zend.php on line 42
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to bootstrap (but not run) the application as well. After what you have, add:

```
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap();
```

you may need to set `APPLICATION_ENV` and `APPLICATION_PATH` as well if you've not already.

Comment: I tired that byt when I use new Admin_Contract_Table(); I get class not found error. I wonder why everything must be so difficult with ZF

Comment: Where is the admin contract table class defined? Do you have an 'admin' module?

Comment: but it does not load models under /application/models, is it normal?

Comment: It depends how you have the autoloaders setup. By default, if you have a bootstrap file for your admin module, application/modules/admin/models/Contacts.php would be a class named `Admin_Model_Contacts`.

Comment: How idiotic is this ZF bootstrap system? Really, I cannot copy with it. I tried everything but I am still failing. I would call it Zend Nightmare instead of Framework. I am reading the ZF quick start and I am seeing how complex and stupid they made it!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't registered  your `Admin` namespace in the autoloader..

`$autoloader->registerNamespace('Admin');`

Comment: where should I do it, in the application bootstrap or in the module bootstrap?

Comment: I treid $autoloader->registerNamespace('Admin'); but it does nothing